# Swift4にてTextFieldのcancelボタンの色を白にしたい

Tags: swift, ios, xcode, iphone

TextFieldをのclearButtonの色を変更したいのですが、簡単に変更できる方法はないのでしょうか。。
簡単に変更できるようであれば教えていただきたいです。

よろしくお願いいたします！

Comment: 簡単に言うと「簡単に変更できる方法」はありません。ざっくり検索すると、(1)private APIを使用する (2)現在のview階層に依存した処理を書く(3)自前のTextFieldクラスを作っちゃう、なんてやり方で頑張った人たちもあるようですが。どれもオススメしたくないですね。

Comment: @OOPerさんコメントありがとうございます。やはりそうなのですね...地道に作成してみたいと思います。ありがとうございました！